# Unable to login via openId with iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, ios-app, stack-exchange-openid

I just went to Apple from Android (Galaxy Nexus to iPhone 6) and am adding various apps.

With the android version of StackExchange, I'm able to log in via OpenId easily.  However, with the iOS variant, I get a `client_id rejected` error message at the OpenID login screen.

Screenshot is attached below.  This screen was reached via tapping the login with another OpenId element at the bottom of the login screen.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you entered correct username and password?

Comment: Correct. There are no fields for text entry. What you see in the screenshot is what appears immediately after selecting 'other openid options'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  I accidentally passed in the wrong value for client_id when cleaning something up. Sorry about that. :(

Comment: Thanks for the update and good to know it was an easy fix. Do you have any idea when the next build will be released?

Comment: Unfortunately it will probably be a few weeks.  I've got a couple more things I'm working on before I can ship.

Comment: Appreciate the update!